# I just want to make animation in iOS

Tags: iphone, animation

I just wanted to create animation for clock to appear as in [this video](http://www.jebril.com/temp/jebril-radio-demo.mp4).

I have no idea how create it. Any solution?

When you click on bulb icon in slider below, the clock will appear and on clicking again clock will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app to be iOS < 4 compatible, use this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear]; //Different Animation Curves available, check docs.
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; //In seconds
//Here do your stuff
int newPosY = myImage.frame.origin.y - 10;
[myImage setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, newPosY, myImage.frame.size.width,     myImage.frame.size.height)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This snippet moves your image 10 pixels up. You can customize the animation making changes to the image frame before calling `commitAnimations`

Also check the [UIView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) to extended info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have this idea in my mind but didn't know how to implement. Let me try. Thanks

Comment: I have tried it. In this scenario the clock will move upward. The lower part of clock should be anchored at some points. Again need help.